# Cannot configure Resharper to use my student account instead of trial

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

I, like many I'm sure, downloaded Resharper and used the trial license to give it a shot. Of course, I liked it and later found out that I qualified for a free student version.

Unfortunately, after signing up for the student version (which doesn't have a license key or rely on the license server), Resharper was still using my trial account, which has since expired.

How do I get Resharper to acknowledge that I am now using the full Student version?

Answer (score 0):

This was easily solved by signing out of my Resharper account and then signing back in. To do this in Visual Studio, click the Resharper tab and then (if currently disabled) click the first option "Why is Resharper disabled?". This will pull open an account window with a Sign Out button.